# MS Access column name with Portuguese accents

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a lot of databases I would like to change their column names. These databases were designed by a team which used Portuguese words for column names. I have managed to change names with spaces but when I try to change the names for columns with Portuguese accents e.g `Instalaçao`, my VBScript fails with error `item not found in this collection`. My VBScript is for changing this column is as below.

```
tblName = "CONSUMIDORES"
oldColName = "[Instalaçao]"
newColName = "INSTALACAO"

Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(dbPath)
Set fld = db.TableDefs(tblName).Fields(oldColName)
fld.Name = newColName
```

This code works for other columns with spaces but for accented words it fails. I am using MS Access 2013. I am new to VBScript.

Comment: The only way I could recreate your issue is if I saved the VBScript file as "UTF-8 without BOM". When saved as "ANSI" it ran fine, and when saved as "UTF-8" (with BOM) cscript.exe choked on the BOM characters. So, verify that your .vbs file is saved with "ANSI" encoding.

Comment: Changing to ANSI worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the file to ANSI as suggested by [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to get away with refering to the fields by number:

```
Set fld = db.TableDefs(tblName).Fields(14)
```

(assuming Instalaçao is the 15th field of that table).